# How to find $(2-\sec^2 1^\circ)(2-\sec^2 2^\circ)\cdots \overline{(2-\sec^2 45^\circ)}\cdots(2-\sec^2 89^\circ)$

Tags: trigonometry

Evaluate
$$(2-\sec^2{1^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{2^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{3^{\circ}})\cdots(2-\sec^2{44^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{46^{\circ}})\cdots(2-\sec^2{89^{\circ}})$$

This same problem come from Problem 21:But that problem is very very easy http://purplecomet.org/home/resource/544/HighSchoolSolutions2013.pdf
$$(2-\sec^2{1^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{2^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{3^{\circ}})\cdots\cdots(2-\sec^2{89^{\circ}})$$

and since $sec^2{45^{\circ}}=2$
so
$$(2-\sec^2{1^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{2^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{3^{\circ}})\cdots(2-\sec^2{89^{\circ}})=0$$

so I ask this follow problem have value?:$$(2-\sec^2{1^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{2^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{3^{\circ}})\cdots(2-\sec^2{44^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{46^{\circ}})\cdots(2-\sec^2{89^{\circ}})$$
Thank you, and this problem is interesting.
we kown that $$2-\sec^2{x}=\dfrac{\sec^2{x}}{\sec{2x}}$$
and we kown 
$$\sin{1^{0}}\sin{2^{0}}\cdots\sin{89^{0}}=\dfrac{6}{4^{45}}\sqrt{10}$$
This  result
use this $$\sin{3x}=4\sin{x}\sin{(x+60^{0})}\sin{(60^{0}-x)}$$

so
$$\cos{1^{0}}\cos{2^{0}}\cdots\cos{89^{0}}=\dfrac{6}{4^{45}}\sqrt{10}$$
so
\begin{align}
&(2-\sec^2{1^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{2^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{3^{\circ}})\cdots(2-\sec^2{44^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{46^{\circ}})\cdots(2-\sec^2{89^{0}})\\
&=\dfrac{cos{2^{0}}\cos{4^{0}}\cdots\cos{88^{0}}(-\sin{2^{0}})(-\sin{4^{0}})\cdots(-\sin{88^{0}})}{\cos^2{1^{0}}\cos^2{2^{0}}\cdots\cos^2{89^{0}}}\\
&=\dfrac{(\sin{4^{0}}\sin{8^{0}}\cdots\sin{88^{0}})^2}{A^2}
\end{align}

where $A=\dfrac{12}{4^{45}}\sqrt{5}$

so we must find $\sin{4^{0}}\sin{8^{0}}\cdots\sin{88^{0}}$
I think must use
$$\sin{3x}=4\sin{x}\sin{(60-x)}\sin{(60+x)}$$

Thank you, I have solve it.
I have this result 
$$(2-\sec^2{1^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{2^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{3^{\circ}})\cdots(2-\sec^2{44^{\circ}})(2-\sec^2{46^{\circ}})\cdots(2-\sec^2{89^{\circ}})=2^{88}$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne45}}^{89}\left(2-\sec^2(k\pi/180)\right)
&=\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne45}}^{89}\left(1-\tan^2(k\pi/180)\right)\tag{1}\\
&=\prod_{\substack{k=1\\k\ne45}}^{89}\left(\frac{\cos^2(k\pi/180)-\sin^2(k\pi/180)}{\cos^2(k\pi/180)}\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{44}\frac{\cos(k\pi/90)}{\cos^2(k\pi/180)}
\prod_{k=46}^{89}\frac{\cos(k\pi/90)}{\cos^2(k\pi/180)}\tag{3}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{44}\frac{\cos(k\pi/90)}{\cos^2(k\pi/180)}
\prod_{k=1}^{44}\frac{-\cos(k\pi/90)}{\sin^2(k\pi/180)}\tag{4}\\
&=(-1)^{44}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{44}\frac{2\cos(k\pi/90)}{\sin(k\pi/90)}\right)^2\tag{5}\\
&=2^{88}\prod_{k=1}^{44}\cot^2(k\pi/90)\tag{6}\\
&=2^{88}\prod_{k=1}^{22}\cot^2(k\pi/90)\prod_{k=23}^{44}\cot^2(k\pi/90)\tag{7}\\
&=2^{88}\prod_{k=1}^{22}\cot^2(k\pi/90)\prod_{k=1}^{22}\tan^2(k\pi/90)\tag{8}\\[6pt]
&=2^{88}\tag{9}
\end{align}
$$
**Justification:**

$(1):$ $\sec^2(x)=1+\tan^2(x)$

$(2):$ $\tan(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$

$(3):$ $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$

$(4):$ $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)$ and $\cos(\pi/2-x)=\sin(x)$

$(5):$ $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

$(6):$ $\cot(x)=\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$

$(7):$ splitting the product

$(8):$ $\cot(\pi/2-x)=\tan(x)$

$(9):$ $\cot(x)\tan(x)=1$

**Mathematica:**

`N[Product[2-Sec[k Pi/180]^2,{k,1,44}]Product[2-Sec[k Pi/180]^2,{k,46,89}],20]`

$3.0948500982134506872\times10^{26}$

`N[2^88, 20]`

$3.0948500982134506872\times10^{26}$

Comment: nice! you alway give me a nice methods,Thank you ,my frend,and someone awalys say my problem is very bad,such as:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408132/find-functions-f-such-that-ffx-xfx1

Comment: I think the post is a very beautiful item, as a result, they are believed to be in a mess

Comment: I believe that you must not think like that,

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Did it originate from Problem 21, or somewhere else? Although Problem 21 is easily solvable because there is a factor of $0$, it is amazing that taking out the factor of $0$ leaves such a nice answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actual problem is to find the value of the Product $P$ and $Q$ where

$$ P= \left(1-{Tan^2{1^\circ}}\right) \left(1-{Tan^2{2^\circ}}\right)\cdots \left(1-{Tan^2{44^\circ}}\right) $$ 
$$ Q= \left(1-{Tan^2{46^\circ}}\right) \left(1-{Tan^2{47^\circ}}\right)\cdots \left(1-{Tan^2{89^\circ}}\right) $$ $\implies$
$$ Q= \left(1-{Cot^2{44^\circ}}\right) \left(1-{Cot^2{43^\circ}}\right)\cdots \left(1-{Cot^2{1^\circ}}\right) $$ 
Let $$ R= Tan{1^\circ} \:Tan{2^\circ}\cdots Tan{44^\circ} $$ So

$$ Q=\frac{P}{R^2}$$ Also

$$ S=\left(1+Tan{1^\circ}\right)\left(1+Tan{2^\circ}\right)\cdots \left(1+Tan{44^\circ}\right)=2^{22} $$ and

$$ T=\left(1-Tan{1^\circ}\right)\left(1-Tan{2^\circ}\right)\cdots \left(1-Tan{44^\circ}\right) $$ so

$$ T=\left(\frac{2Tan{44^\circ}}{1+Tan{44^\circ}}\right) \left(\frac{2Tan{43^\circ}}{1+Tan{43^\circ}}\right) \cdots \left(\frac{2Tan{1^\circ}}{1+Tan{1^\circ}}\right)$$ So

$$ T=\frac{2^{44}R}{S}=2^{22}R$$ But

$$P=ST=2^{44}R$$ So

$$Q=\frac{P}{R^2}=\frac{2^{44}}{R}$$ Finally

$$PQ=2^{88}$$

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the answer won't be anything nice. You've removed essentially the only trick to this problem and now you just have the product of a bunch of almost unrelated numbers. Note that the later terms will start getting quite large so the actual value will be very large (of the order of $10^{26}$)

Comment: No,I don't think so,But thank you all the same

Comment: There's really no reason at all for this to be something significant though. Cosine functions don't change in a nice way (e.g. linearly) and cos(1) certainly isn't a nice value (I don't believe we even have an exact value for it in involving only roots, powers, etc. in a finite representation).

Comment: $2^{88}$ may not be nice, but it is nicer than the original.

Comment: oh wow. This is quite surprising to me. It uses a result I've never seen before but it's really quite cool. Thanks @robjohn

Comment: @john: which result is uncommon? I tried to break everything down to pretty basic steps.

Comment: I've actually never seen the result $\sin (1) \sin (2) \ldots \sin (89) = 6 \sqrt{10} / 4^{45}$ before

Comment: @john: oh, I thought you were talking about my answer. I just added line-by-line justification.

Comment: ahh, just noticed. Very elegant!