# Is there a non-trivial general solution to the ODE f'(x)=f(f(x))?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE f'(x)=f(f(x)), also written as y'=y°y, far surpasses the level at which I learnt the theory and paractice of ODEs, and I am not even sure it has a solution (that is non-trivial). 
This is not a problem I have encountered anywhere, but rather a thought that is bothering me for quite a while.
I have tried proving a non-trivial solution for such a problem does not exist, using various methods (mainly using Picard-Lindëlof theorem in various ways), but in vain. I have also tried finding such a solution, with similiar success.

So, how do I even handle such a problem? Is there a non-trivial solution? And if so, what is the solution? 
Are there any physical interpretations to such an ODE?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408004/does-a-non-trivial-solution-exist-for-fx-ffx