# Solve $f(f(x))=f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Treated with the inverse operator, one could get: $f(x)=x$

However, an other obvious solution is $f(x)=C$ (when f is not invertible). How could I reach this solution? Are there other solutions available?

---

This is not a homework.

To prove the uniqueness of the solution, I am trying (and currently failing) to do something similar to:
[Does a non-trivial solution exist for $f'(x)=f(f(x))$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408004/does-a-non-trivial-solution-exist-for-fx-ffx/1151279#1151279)

---

Thank you Jack and V. Your efforts help. I wonder if one could prove that the "projectors" are the only family of solution to Idempotence.

Comment: There are many other solutions such as the absolute value function $x \mapsto |x|$, or the integer part function $x \mapsto \operatorname{floor}(x)$ (and many more).

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours An involution is its own inverse, that isn't the case here since $f(f(x))=f(x)$ if I understand correctly

Comment: Such property is called [Idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)

Comment: My bad, misread the question. Will delete the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any projection operator does the job.
For instance, let $K$ be some closed, unbounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ the function mapping $x$ to $\min\left( K \cap [x,+\infty)\right)$. Then $f(f(x))=f(x)$.

The general structure of an idempotent map is the following one: we have $\mathbb{R}=A\cup B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $\forall a\in A, f(a)\in B$ together with $\forall b\in B, f(b)=b$. Then $B=\text{Im}\,f$ and $\forall r\in\mathbb{R},\,f(f(r))=f(r)$.

Comment: Are there any rigorous proof I could find on this? Is the operator in your solution the only family of solutions?

Comment: @LowGPA: to check that such $f$ fulfills $ff=f$ is straightforward, but there are plenty of projection operators. For instance, you may consider the map that sets to $0$ the binary or decimal digits in certain positions, the map that does essentially the same with respect to a Hamel basis etcetera.

Comment: Well, projector ($P^2=P$) seems like merely re-dictating the question itself. But your answer is great and I will accept it if no others come.

Comment: @LowGPA: anyway, I have added a complete characterization of idempotent maps over $\mathbb{R}$. There are plenty of them since there are many ways for partitioning $\mathbb{R}$ into two components and many ways for mapping the $A$-component into the $B$-component.

Answer (score 1):

The function 
$f(x) = \max(x,0).$

Also absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict yourself to linear operators, such a mapping would be a projector. The identity is an example of a projector from $\mathbb{R}$ onto itself. 
A constant function, even though it is not linear, can be seen as the null application translated to your constant.
If you define a proper affine subspace, then you can find a projector, so I guess there is no uniqueness

Answer (score 1):

Any such function is a "choice of representatives" function for some equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$. In fact, this works on any set $X$, not just $\mathbb R$. Fix any equivalence relation on $X$ and let $f(x)$ map each $x$ to some fixed representative of the equivalence class of $x$, then $f$ satisfies your condition. Conversely, if $f\circ f=f$, let the equivalence relation be $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$.

Let's say that an $f$ corresponding to a given partition of $X$ is a *projection* for that partition.

If $X$ is a metric space, then a given partition admits a continuous projection if and only if every class of the partition is a closed set, in which case *every* projection for that partition is continuous.

So there (at least) as many continuous solutions to $f\circ f=f$ on $\mathbb R$ as there are partitions of $\mathbb R$ into closed sets.