# Number of continuously differentiable functions satisfying $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)=f(f(x))$?

Tags: calculus, functions

Number of continuously differentiable functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)=f(f(x))$ for all $x$ belonging to the set of real numbers are?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @preferred_anon no, I haven't solved this kind of problem previously. Any hints on how to start?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I don't think it is. The remark needed to answer this question (that any such solution is decreasing) is directly credited to a Putnam problem, which I suspect is exactly where this question came from.

Comment: @Tapi your question body says $f(x) > 0$, but your title says $f'(x) > 0$. Which do you mean?

Comment: @preferred_anon fixed it! It's $f(x)>0$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Ah! You win.

Comment: @preferred_anon Actually the argument used there might be wrong  Edit: Nevermind, I understand it now; here is the link for other people: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/408114/631742